# How to align EditText beside button in the center of screen?

Tags: android, layout, center

I want to add `EditText` beside Button in the center of screen  without using margin to appear permanently in the  center of all sizes of screens, for `EditText` I used

```
android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical" and android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
```

for button, I tested it on my nexus 7 screen but it's appear at the left of the screen as shown in photo

[image]

I am not able to figure-out the problem.

Please help me !!!

This is the XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:ems="10"  
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#c7c7c7"
        android:width="250dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"

        android:background="#359c5e"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to set  `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to your `LinearLayout`

Comment: Please post UI image for how you want to show it

Comment: thanks Naveen, i try this and the problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would preffer using RelativeLayout as a root Layout then you can apply   `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` property to LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#c7c7c7"
            android:width="250dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="#359c5e"
            android:onClick="geoLocate"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Go"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/topLayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @AymanEmad If your issue is solved after using above code snippet then  you can close the question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For `EditText`, set `android:layout_width` to `0dip` and `android:layout_weight` to `1`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#c7c7c7"
        android:width="250dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="#359c5e"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: If this solution solves your problem then please, accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#c7c7c7"
        android:width="250dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="#359c5e"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```